# Will trading the same pokemon increase the chance of getting Lucky Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I trade, say, Pikachu, for my friend's Pikachu.

Will the chance of getting a Lucky Pokemon increase when trading two of the same Pokemon than two different Pokemon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Trading the same Pokemon does not affect the chance.

However, if one of the Pokemon was obtained more than a year ago, [then the chance of a Lucky Pokemon increases as per this previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336527/what-are-the-chances-of-getting-a-lucky-pok%C3%A9mon).

Comment: While there is no hard statistical evidence and probably just extremely lucky RNG, I’ve actually more luck with getting lucky Pokémon with same-species trade. I got six lucky Snorlaxes during the “Snoozing with Snorlax” event last year; two shiny Blazikens after community day; back-to-back Alolan Geodudes; and a few others. Again, probably just extremely lucky RNG, but I’m curious if the OPs question has some merit